# Alternative definition for the value of stochastic solution

Tags: stochastic-programming

I have a two-stage stochastic programming problem in which the expected-value solution results in a quite different first-stage solution than the recourse problem. Although the value of VSS (defined below) is often positive, it is somewhat negligible.

> The Value of Stochastic Solution (VSS) is defined as the difference
>   between the Expectation of the Expected Value Solution (EEVS) and the
>   optimal objective value of the Recourse Problem (RP).

This definition only considers the objective function values to determine the merits of the stochastic solution. I think this is not a good index in the sense that it does not consider the structure of the solutions. I was wondering if there are any other index for evaluating the merits of a stochastic problem in comparison to the expected value problem? I feel that this has already been studied in the literature, but I could not find a reference.

**EDIT:** It should mention that the stochastic program with a large number of scenarios can be solved efficiently, so I am not looking for a way to speedup solving the SP by reducing the number of first-stage variables or by reducing the number of scenarios. I just want a measure to quantify the value of stochastic solution. I thought maybe this has something to do with robustness or robust optimization, but RO is a different field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the paper by Crainic et al.<sup>1</sup>, the authors stated that "Focusing on two-stage formulations, we show how and under which conditions the reduced costs associated to the variables in the deterministic formulation can be used as an indicator for excluding/retaining decision variables in the stochastic model. We introduce a new measure, the **Loss of Reduced Costs-based Variable Fixing (LRCVF)**, computed as the difference between the optimal values of the stochastic problem and its reduced version obtained by fixing a certain number of variables.

Maggioni et al.<sup>2</sup> proposed the concepts of the **Value of the Right Distribution (VRD)**, **the Performance Bound (PB)** and the **Worst-Case Performance Bound (WPB)**, which can be applied to quantify how much the lost will be if we guess the wrong distribution of the uncertain parameters affecting a stochastic optimization problem. They applied these concepts in two-stage stochastic programming model of the cost-based variant of the classical Newsvendor problem.

I think above-mentioned papers can give you a good start point in searching for alternative indexes for VSS.

[1] Crainic, Teodor G., et al. "Reduced cost-based variable fixing in two-stage stochastic programming." Annals of Operations Research (2018): 1-37.

[2] Maggioni, Francesca, Matteo Cagnolari, and Luca Bertazzi. "The value of the right distribution in stochastic programming with application to a Newsvendor problem." Computational Management Science (2019): 1-20.

Comment: Formatting tip: Note that writing `<sup>1</sup>` yields a superscript 1 instead of resorting to MathJax.